# fill series with additional value vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

hi how can I make a fill series if I want it like this

**GEE-2019-000**

**GEE-2019-001**

**GEE-2019-002** and so on...

here's my code for the fill series I just want to add **GEE-2019-**

```
Dim Lst As Long
      Lst = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           With Range("A1")
             .Value = "1"
             .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1").Resize(Lst), Type:=xlFillSeries
     End With
```

but I don't know how...
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have access to Excel to test these out.  Going from memory.

Does it have to be with VBA?

Excel can sometimes guess at the series you want to fill.  Have you tried entering "**GEE-2019-000**" in A1, "**GEE-2019-001**" in A2, select both cells, then drag the fill handle down (or double-click the fill handle if you want to automagically fill down to the row populated in an adjacent column), and, if necessary, select **Fill Series** in the fill handle menu?

Does it **have** to have "**GEE-2019-001**" as text in the cell, or can it just **display** "**GEE-2019-001**" when you enter 1 (as a numeric value, not a text string) in the cell.  You can set up custom number formats for the cells you want to display "**GEE-2019-001**" when you enter a numeric value of **1**.  This way, the cell can have a numeric value that can be used in calculations, but also just **display** text in the cell along with your value.  With these custom formats, you will setup formats for up to 4 different types of values:  {positive numbers};{negative numbers};{value of zero};{text}.

Let's use budget surplus/deficits as an example:  You could have surpluses show in the cell "Surplus: {dollar amount}" in a green font; and deficits show "Deficit: {dollar amount;with or without a negative (-) sign}" in red font...once again, text will **show** in the cell, but will hold a numeric value that can be used in calculations.   I don't recall the exact syntax to do this, but if you look up custom number formats in Excel's help, it will list a wealth of information.